# Unable to fetch document

Tags: javascript, sql, pouchdb, cloudant, nosql

I am currently using cordova barcode scanner.

What I want to do is after I scan the `QR code` which contain a certain number, I will fetch the doc from my `cloudant` db and display the information in the doc.

However, no matter how I try, I kept getting `404 error`, which is document not found, although I do have a document with a `_id` of `2`.

Whenever I scan the `QR code`, the result I get is `2`, so I thought it might require a double quote around it, thus I did the escape double quote. Yet, it still didn't work. May I know why?

**This is my code:**

```
 cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
            var myTextTwo = result.text;
            db.get("\"" + myTextTwo + "\"", function (err, doc) {
                if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            alert(doc.price);
            alert(doc.productName);
                });
});
```

Comment: Do you know what the full URL is that the request goes to?  Maybe take a look at that and see if there's anything obvious wrong there.  I don't think you need the quotes, but if it wasn't working without them either then that's probably not your actual problem.

Comment: Hi, @LornaMitchell, I believe he is using PouchDB in this specific example. (Alvin, please feel free to clarify.)

Comment: @LornaMitchell Yes, Jason is right. I am using PouchDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the quotes around it, try converting `myTextTwo` into a String type. For example:

```
var id = String(result.text); // This ensures id is a string.
db.get(id, function (err, doc) {
    // (etc. The rest of your code looks good)
});
```